# CondaVerificationError when installing PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, miniconda

I am trying to install pytorch using either of below command and I got a lot of error. I am using windows CPU only.

```
conda install pytorch::pytorch

or 
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
```

some of the error are

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/torchgen/static_runtime/gen_static_runtime_ops.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/torchgen/static_runtime/generator.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/torchgen/utils.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/torchgen/yaml_utils.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Scripts/convert-caffe2-to-onnx-script.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Scripts/convert-onnx-to-caffe2-script.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\test\miniconda3\pkgs\pytorch-2.2.1-py3.10_cpu_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Scripts/torchrun-script.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your packages seems to be corrupt. You can try cleaning the packages from cache and reinstalling pytorch:

```
conda clean -p
```

Comment: This might work, but typically one needs to manually delete the unzipped package in the cache since if the package is installed elsewhere Conda will not consider it eligible for `conda clean -p`.